# How does Islam define wisdom

Tags: knowing-islam

What—*according to Islam*—is wisdom?

According to Confucius, *"... wisdom (Zhi) recognize knowing a thing as knowing it, and ignorance of a thing as ignorance of it."* (Analects, 2.17).

According to Aristotle, *"... wisdom (Sophia) is knowledge, combined with intuitive reason, of the things that are highest by nature.”* (Nicomachean Ethics, VI, 1141b).

Answer (score -1):

> 1/1 (Al-Kulayni's disciples say): Abu Ja`far Muhammad ibn Ya`qub
> (al-Kulayni, the compiler of al-Kafi informed us, saying: A group of
> our companions (i.e. al-Kulayni's teachers), among them Muhammad ibn
> Yahya al-`Altar1, narrated to us from Ahmad ibn Muhammad2 , he from al-Hasan ibn Mahbub3, from al 'Ata' ibn Razin4 , from Muhammad ibn Muslims5 from Abu Ja'far (al-'Imam al-Baqir) (A) that he said:   When God created the Intellect (al-`Aql), He examined it. Thereupon He said
> to it: `Come forward!' It came forward. Then He said:` Go back!' It
> went back. Thereupon He said: `By My power and majesty, I didn't create any creature dearer to me than thee! I will not make thee perfect except in one whom I love. Indeed, to thee are My orders and-prohibitions addressed. And for you are My rewards and retributions reserved.' 2/10: (Al-Kulayni from) Muhammad ibn Yahya, from Ahmad ibn Muhammad, from (al-Hasan) ibn Mahbub, from` Abd Allah ibn Sinan6, who
> said:   I mentioned to Abu `Abd Allah (al-'Imam al-Sadiq) (A) about a man afflicted with (doubts about)wudu' (ritual ablutions) and salat; remarking that he was a man of intellect (`aqil)- Abu `Abd Allah (A) said:` What kind of intellect has he 'when he obeys Satan! ' I said:
> `How does he obey Satan?' He said:` Ask him about its cause and he
> will tell you that it is the work of Satan.'   3/27: A group of our
> companions, from Ahmad ibn Muhammad, from al-Haytham ibn Abi Masruq
> al-Nahdi7; from al-Husayn ibn Khalid8, from Ishaq ibn `Ammar9, who said:   I asked Abu` Abd Allah (A): `How is it that certain people
> understand everything on being told a little (about some matter) and
> some people are such that they hear the whole thing and respond to it;
> but there are some others who on being told (about a matter) ask one
> to repeat it again?'
>
> The Imam (A) said: `O Ishaq, do you know why that is so? The man who
> understands the whole (matter) on hearing a little is one whose
> intellect was kneaded with his (substance) at the spermatic stage. The
> one who hears the whole thing and responds in accordance with what you
> had told him, is one whose intellect developed in his mother's womb.
> And the man who requests you to repeat is one whose intellect
> developed after he grew up.'

[Reference](https://www.al-islam.org/al-tawhid/general-al-tawhid/selections-usul-al-kafi-shaykh-muhammad-ibn-yaqub-al-kulayni/i-book)

[More info](https://www.al-islam.org/tags/intellect)